# Dropbox + Chrome Extension Oauth Receiver

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, dropbox-api

I am trying to create a small extension. I got it all working outside of the extension and am trying to migrate.

All I get is "Dropbox sign-in successful" but no redirect or idea of what is supposed to happen next.

I am using the following for the authentication (and I have no real idea what they do). I have been spending time understanding the manifest.json and I think the solution lies elsewhere. Any help is appreciated!

**chrome_oauth_receiver.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.0-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="chrome_oauth_receiver.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dropbox sign-in successful</h1>
    <p>Please close this window.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**chrome_oauth_receiver.js**

```
Dropbox.AuthDriver.Chrome.oauthReceiver();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Dropbox",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.dropbox.com/; object-src 'self'",
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : [
            "jquery.min.js",
            "dropbox-datastores.js",
            "markdown.min.js",
            "popup.js"
        ],
        "persistent" : false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "https://*.dropbox.com/*"
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "chrome_oauth_receiver.html"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html and popup.js is basically the code from here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/71/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk

Comment: Try loading Dropbox API from the CDN instead of bundling it, as in `<script src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.0-latest.js"></script>`. You already have CSP set up for that.

Comment: According to the docs it's `Dropbox.AuthDriver.Chrome` instead of `Dropbox.AuthDriver.ChromeExtension` https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.AuthDriver

Comment: You were correct, that removed the error message. But what is supposed to happen afterwards? Right now it just says "Dropbox sign-in successful Please close this window." Should it not redirect or finalize the authentication?

Comment: CSP = Concentrated Solar Power? :)

Comment: CSP = Content Security Policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current [**dropbox-sdk-js v2**](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) you need to obtain your **authUrl**

```
const Dropbox = require('dropbox'),
      // your extension ID url + chrome oauth receiver
      fullReceiverPath = 'chrome-extension://imkoifkgjagghnncjkhggdhalmcnfklk/html/chrome_oauth_receiver.html',
      // App key from https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/ 
      APIKEY = 'k1ff2saf035rn7c';


let dbc = new Dropbox({clientId: APIKEY}),
    authToken = '',
    authUrl = dbc.getAuthenticationUrl(fullReceiverPath);
    // expected returned value - https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=k1ff2saf035rn7c&redirect_uri=chrome-extension://imkoifkgjagghnncjkhggdhalmcnfklk
```

Don not forget to whitelist **/html/chrome_oauth_receiver.html** in your **manifest.json**:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [ "html/chrome_oauth_receiver.html"]
```

To understand better, red the  [chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)

And finally, this is simple example of your **chrome_oauth_receiver.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     var token = window.location.hash;
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'dropboxConnectToken', content: token});
     window.location.hash = '';
     if (window.close) {
       return window.close();
     }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Dropbox sign-in successful</h1>
  <p>Please close this window.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when you use standard [chrome-extension message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) you will obtain URL hash with token. Its now just a detail to parse it.

Good luck!